# How can I programmatically add or update JavaScript origin urls for my oauthclient?

Tags: javascript, api, google-oauth

We have a portal that allows for custom subdomains for schools where the branding/style can be customized for each. We add these in the console.developers.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/...etc.. area of the Google APIs developer console. This lets users login to any of the custom portals with their same Google account.

I would like to programmatically be able to add these JavaScript Origins URLs for new school portals and update them for subdomain changes. Is there a way to do this? I would prefer to use a Google SDK library for .NET. Updating these manually works fine but we are trying to automate as much of the process as possible.

Comment: ***"I would prefer to use a Google SDK library for .NET."*** -  What have you tried  so far?

Comment: I've been looking through the API documentation but I haven't found anything yet but I'll keep digging.